# CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes 's width and height parameters

Tags: iphone, html5-video, core-video

seems like the Core Video's CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes allows width and height to be 320 and 480.

If I try 160, and 240 the image is clicked.

But I really like create an image that has smaller dimension.

Comment: What does mean "clicked"? Could you provide screenshot?